# equivalent statements about a real integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f: [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ integrable. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> $1) \int_a^b |f(x)|dx=0;$
>
> $2) \mbox{ if } f \mbox{ is continuous at point }  c \mbox{ then } f(c)=0;$
>
> $3) \mbox{ int}(X=\{x\in[a,b]; f(x)\neq 0\})=\emptyset.$

For $1\Longrightarrow 2$ i tried:

Since $f$ is integrable, it follows that $|f|$ is integrable and
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\leq\int_a^b|f(x)|dx=0 \Longrightarrow \int_a^b f(x)dx=0.
$$

Moreover, since $f$ is continuous in $c$, then the function
$$
F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt
$$
is derivable in $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)$.

Now, if $F'(c)\neq0$ then either $F'(c)>0$ or $F'(c)<0$. Assume $F'(c)>0$. Thus, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$
x,y\in(a,b) \mbox{ and } c-\delta<x<c<y<c+\delta \Longrightarrow F(x)<F(c)<F(y).
$$

I'm stuck here. Any tips?

Comment: I'm guessing from your first step that the integral in question is the Lebesgue integral? If that is the case, I suggest tagging this question with [tag:lebesgue-integral]

Comment: @TheoBendit Is there a reason it can't be Riemann integration?

Comment: it is riemann integrable

Comment: @Arthur I guess not. I confused $f$ being integrable $\implies$ $|f|$ is integrable with its converse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Work only with $|f|$. The positivity of $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ does not guarantee that $f(c) = 0$.

Since $||f(x)| - |f(c)|| \leqslant |f(x) - f(c)|$, the function $|f|$ is continuous at $c$.  If $|f(c)| > 0$ then $|f(x)| > |f(c)|/2 > 0$ on some interval $I \subset [a,b]$.  Now find a contradiction.